# How to add new queues to JBoss A-MQ using the command line console interface?

Tags: jboss, jms, jbossfuse, jbossmq, jboss-amq

I'm trying to add queues to a running JBoss A-MQ service.

Currently I can do it manually via the Web interface, as shown below:
[image: Red Hat JBoss A-MQ Web Console]

But, I would like to use the A-MQ Command Console to do it:
[image: Red Hat JBoss A-MQ Command Line Interfacee]

What would be the JBoss A-MQ Console command equivalent to the "Create" button on the Web Interface?

I've searched the [official documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_A-MQ/6.1/html/Console_Reference/files/ConsoleRefIntro.html), but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no commands in the A-MQ command console currently to do so. But it is a good idea, so I have logged a ticket to implement such commands

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5178

Comment: Thanks @Claus! Are you aware of any other method to create such queues programatically?

Comment: You can use the JMS API or JMX API

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, AMQ 7 has a command-line interface to create queues.